How to issue an access token after account confirmation in AWS Cognito in a passwordless flow (combined sign-up/sign-in page)?
I've implemented a passwordless login system in AWS Cognito and aiming to streamline the user experience based on a flow I've seen in real-world apps.
In my case, I'm using AWS Cognito with a passwordless login setup as described here. Currently, when a user signs up, they receive a confirmation code to verify their account using Cognito's built-in verification system. After confirming their account, they must log in again to receive the access token, which sends another confirmation code to their email.
However, requiring the user to check their inbox twice—once for account confirmation and again for login—leads to a poor user experience, especially in a mobile app setting.
My desired flow looks like this: The user encounters a combined sign-up/sign-in page with only one field where they input their email address.
This unified process applies whether the user is signing up for the first time or signing in as a returning user.

Here's a real world example I've seen:
Enter your (sign-up / sign-in) email: 
Enter the verification code: 
After that you're in, no matter if it's the first time or you're returning.

I've checked AWS's docs and played around with Cognito's built-in capabilities like the post-confirmation Lambda trigger, but this doesn't seem to contain all required information to authenticate a user signing up.
For example, is there a way to issue the access token immediately after the account confirmation step, so the user doesn't have to log in again? I want to ensure the user completes the process with just one code, whether they are signing up or signing in.
Any guidance on how to implement this combined sign-up / sign-in in AWS Cognito would be much appreciated!

Once I implemented passwordless login using a phone number, I first needed to know about Cognito setup. On my solution, I turned off mfa configurations to prevent Cognito from sending codes. Then, I marked Authentication flows as CUSTOM_AUTH_FLOW_ONLY on my App client. You can use SES on createAuthChallange to send OTP code to User.

@LahiruPathum this is what I already have, sending OTPs via SES with not MFA enabled. My issue is not with sending verification codes via email but combining the sign-up with login flow.

Ok. So you don't need to send a verify code on signup because every time user login it verify the email. When signup you can do autoConfirmUser  and autoVerifyEmail on preSignUp trigger. Then first do Signup call its success then login call. Also you need to check UserExistingException on Signup
